# Updating GNU make on macOS

Tags: macos, gnu-make

I downloaded GNU make 4.2.1 from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/) (make-4.2.1.tar.gz) and installed it following the instruction found in the INSTALL file that is present in the expanded folder.
Now I run `make -v` in the shell and I still get that the system sees the old version:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Any suggestion?
I'm working on a macOS 10.12.3 machine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason not to use **homebrew**? It is brilliant for any Mac and makes it dead easy to install anything - make, find, sed, awk, ImageMagick...

Comment: Well, simply didn't know this tool. :) Now I'll google it and give it a try. Does it get rid of 'trash' installs I did in the past?

Comment: It won't tidy up or remove anything you have done in the past, but it is very easy to add and remove packages going forward. Want a `YouTubeDownloader`? Just `brew search tube`. Want to install `jhead`, just `brew install jhead`. Want to try `GNU Parallel`? Just `brew install parallel`. Don't like it? Just `brew rm parallel`. Perfect!

Comment: `brew install make` is currently giving me an `502 Bad Gateway`, alternative solutions to `brew` are also very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad practice to alter the contents of `/usr/bin`. The best way is to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` :

```
[[ "$PATH" = */usr/local/bin* ]] || PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type command `which make`. If nothing unexpected happens, the shell will print out `/usr/bin/make`, which is the path of default `make`.

In INSTALL file:

> By default, `make install` will install the package's files in
>   `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/man`, etc.  You can specify an
>   installation prefix other than `/usr/local` by giving configure the
>   option `--prefix=PATH`.

So maybe you can try `make --prefix=/usr/bin`. Or remove the default `make` create soft link for `make` in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: It is ill-advised to install or remove anything to/from `/usr/bin`. In fact, the System Integrity Protection feature of modern versions of macOS will prevent this, even with root permissions.