# How to make terminal use newer version of GNU make(4.3) instead of default old(3.81) one?

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnu-make

I tried to update my `make` to the newer version via **HomeBrew**, using command

```
brew upgrade make
```

which returns

```
Warning: make 4.3 already installed
```

but when I run

```
make -v
```

it shows that it is still using the older version(3.81)

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When searched online I found out that I have to set my **PATH environment variable** to `"/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in order to fix this issue.

but my path variable already have `/usr/local/bin:` in front of it when seen via `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

then what should I do in order to update it ?

---

P.S.

> brew version - Homebrew 2.5.8

> OS - macOS Catalina 10.15.7

- These are the following links I have already seen when searched online : -

  1 [updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175529/updating-make-version-4-1-on-mac)

  2 [updating-gnu-make-on-macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026502/updating-gnu-make-on-macos)

Comment: Run `type make` to see what you are actually running.

Comment: Or maybe just try running `hash -r` first and then try `make -v` again.

Comment: Or open a new terminal and try it there.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is running `/usr/bin/make` when checked through `type make` which I think is the one which came by default with the system.

Comment: @MadScientist doing the same in new window also results in same

Comment: What happens if you run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/make`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `ls -l /usr/bin/make` returns `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 Sep 22 05:59 /usr/bin/make`

Comment: Sorry, `/usr/LOCAL/bin/make` please.

Comment: @MarkSetchell now this is interesting, it is saying that it doesn't exist. I even manually searched for `make` in `ls -l /usr/local/bin` but couldn't find it there. then why does brew gave such error ?

Comment: Try `brew info make` to see if you missed anything.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you are correct, from `brew info make` i found out that`GNU "make" has been installed as "gmake"`, which means path environmental variable will be different `/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH`

Comment: Or you need to run `gmake`.

Comment: that's true, thanks for your time @MarkSetchell :)

Comment: I add it as an answer so that future readers can see without scrambling through the comments. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a check what's up with:

```
brew info make
```

> GNU "make" has been installed as "gmake".
> If you need to use it as "make", you can add a "gnubin" directory
> to your PATH from your bashrc like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

So, you can either do what is suggested above and change your PATH, or use `gmake` instead of `make`.